# Do you need to declare datatype of a variable in Swift?

Tags: swift

In Swift Programming, should we need to declare datatype of the variable or will the variable change it's type based on value?

Which one is enough to declare a variable:

```
var MyVar: Int = 50
```

Or:

```
var Myvar = 50
```

Comment: Just a notice that none of the your examples are variable, they're both constants, you need to use var instead

Comment: Both are enough to declare the constant, but for the second one the compiler will infer the type as an integer. It saves on a little bit of code/time, but still allows for the safety of explicit typing.

Comment: There's no such thing as `int`. It's `Int`.

Comment: @VigneshKumar - Please stop adding the swift-ios tag. It's redundant and should not be used.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ```
> var myVar: Int = 50
> ```
>
> Or:
>
> ```
> var myVar = 50
> ```

They are absolutely equivalent. The `: Int` is unnecessary because you are assigning `50` right there in the declaration, so Swift infers that this is to be an Int variable.

If you are going to assign as part of the declaration, the only time you need to supply the type is when the type is surprising. For example:

```
var myChar : Character = "s"
```

If you don't say Character, you'll get a String.

Answer (score 4):

**WWDC 2104 - Introduction To Swift (Session 402)**

```
var languageName = “Swift”            // inferred as String
var version = 1.0                     // inferred as Double
var introduced = 2014                 // inferred as Int
var isAwesome = true                  // inferred as Bool
```

Also…

```
var  = “Frog”                       // using unicode names
```

You should also use “let” for variables that will not change.

Answer (score 1):

Type inference is one of the great parts of Swift.  This means that when you assign a variable or constant, the system infers what type it should be.  If for instance, you were declaring a variable before you set it, you'd need to specify its type explicitly.

```
var someVar: Int

someVar = 15
```

That way the compiler knows when it is being properly set.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable implicitly as:
`var myVar = 50`
or explicitly as:
`var myVar:Int = 50`

Also notice that you do not use the semi-colon `;` to end the line.

Note that values are never implicitly converted to another type. If you need to convert a value to a different type, explicitly make an instance of the desired type, such as the following:

```
let label = "The width is "
let width = 94
let widthLabel = label + String(width)
```

Answer (score 1):

From a complete beginner's view (mine) i see the following benefit of declaring a variable explicitly - the compiler will validate the input value - i.e. if you declare an empty variable and then update it with the wrong type value you will be prompted.

Answer (score 0):

The first seems to be used only integer assignment.
I need to write code to test.

Update:

I mean, 
Defined as int can not assign to string, the following is wrong：

```
var myVar: Int
myVar = "50"
```

And such is wrong：

```
var myVar
myVar = "50"
```

So, if assignment when you define a variable, use both two.
Otherwise, use:

```
var myVar: Int
```

Therefore, it is no difference between the two lists you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I changed `MyVar` to `myVar` to follow the convention.

```
var myVar: Int = 50
```

means -> message to the compiler will be.

**Declare a variable called `myVar` that is `of type`(`:`) `Int`**

and

```
var myVar = 50
```

will result the exact same. But here compiler will deduce the type for us. (Welcome to modern intelligent compilers). **`Type inference`** is strong feature of swift language.

### Be aware that Swift is Type Safe Language